# Need allocate physical memory in a specified way and use it for DMA (X86_64 linux system)

Tags: memory-management, linux-device-driver, dma

[image]

I am very new to linux driver programming.

I want use any one of the  physical memory regions shaded in red for our testing .(ie 3.7GB- 4.3Gb or 7.7 or 8.3GB , basically the memory region should be crossing the 4GB boundary) .  This memory will be used for DMAing from/to PCI adapters.

My idea is:

1) Reserve Needed portion of physical memory at boot using the kernel boot line "memmap" 
2) Use ioremap to get virtual address and pass it to dma_map_single 
3)  Use  "dma_map_single"  to get dma bus handle 
4) Use "dma_declare_coherent_memory" with DMA_EXCLUSIVE flag to setup dma memories from the addresses we got from Step 2 and Step 3 
5) Set  "dma_set_mask_and_coherent" for 64 bits just incase. 
6) If Above steps  succeed then all "dma_alloc_coherent" will take memory from the region we expect. So that we will be able to test our scenario.

Please let us know if the above idea will work or if our understanding is wrong. Also point us if there is any other way of doing this. 

Current State:
Since in most of systems 3.7GB to 4GB is reserved , I am forced to use regions from 7.7GB-8.3GB or 11.7 to 12.3GB.

Dmesg Output from a system:

BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
 BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 0000000000099000 (usable) 
 BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000cd2f0000 (usable) 
 BIOS-e820: 00000000cd2f0000 - 00000000cd31c000 (reserved) 
 BIOS-e820: 00000000cd31c000 - 00000000cd35b000 (ACPI data) 
 BIOS-e820: 00000000cd35b000 - 00000000d0000000 (reserved) 
 BIOS-e820: 00000000e0000000 - 00000000f0000000 (reserved) 
 BIOS-e820: 00000000fe000000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved) 
 BIOS-e820: 0000000100000000 - 0000000430000000 (usable)

I tried to do it using the following kernel boot option
  memmap="60M$0x1be200000"           << reserves 60MB start at address 7.7GB

I am seeing kernel panic if I tried to do this.All of the systems server are having more than 10GB of ram.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Your step #2 is wrong.  **phys_to_virt()** requires that the memory to already have a mapping in kernel address space.  Between your step #1 and #2, you have done nothing to map the physical memory with virtual memory.

Comment: So I have to do ioremap and pass that virutal address to dma_map_single ??

Comment: `ioremap()` is not applicable to memory regions in general.